# Some problems when loading weights in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I searched lots of resources to solve this issue, but still stuck here.

I followed the pytorch tutorial and saved parameters with

```
torch.save(the_model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

then loaded parameters with

```
the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
the_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

After I loaded parameters, I printed my model. It came out an error.

```
IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys=[], unexpected_keys=[])
```

I found some people facing the same problem, but it seems that it can be ignored?! Then I try to input data into model with ```model.forward()''', it came out another error.

```
AttributeError: 'IncompatibleKeys' object has no attribute 'forward'
```

I know this kind of saving method(`the_model.state_dict()`) is just save "weights". It should be used only `.eval()` due to some important information not be saved (dropout, batchnorm, etc.). So I try `model.eval()`, it still has the same error.

```
AttributeError: 'IncompatibleKeys' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

Here's are some relative code:

- Initialize model:

  `model = VAE(some constructor parameters)`
- After training:

  ```
  checkpoint_path = os.path.join(save_path, "E%02d.pkl" % ep)
  torch.save(model.state_dict(), checkpoint_path)
  ```
- Initialize a same model and load parameters into model:

  ```
  model = VAE(some constructor parameters)
  checkpoint = torch.load("E24.pkl", map_location='cuda:0')
  model = model.load_state_dict(checkpoint)
  ```

I won't train this model anymore. I just want to load parameters then check the performance. Thanks for reading. :)

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE], in particular we need your `TheModelClass` otherwise it is impossible to reproduce your error.

Comment: If the information is still not enough, please tell me.

Comment: Is `VAE` the same as `TheModelClass`? Can you please post the code that defines either of these? If I just take any model of my choice this ususally works, so to help you we *have* to know how that class is defined, and preferably also have an example of the file you saved the state dict too.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if we can't paste the minimal code you provide into a script and run it to reproduce your error then it's probably not enough. (This is effectively what is meant by minimal, complete, and reproducible)